# How to find the count of same values in a row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

The dataframe is as follows:

```
a     |   b    |   c    |   d
-------------------------------
TRUE    FALSE    TRUE     TRUE
FALSE   FALSE    FALSE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
TRUE    FALSE    TRUE     FALSE
```

I need to find the count of the TRUE's in each column.
The last row should contain the count as follows:

```
a     |   b    |   c    |   d  |  count
---------------------------------------
TRUE    FALSE    TRUE     TRUE     3
FALSE   FALSE    FALSE    TRUE     1
TRUE    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     4
TRUE    FALSE    TRUE     FALSE    2
```

The logic I tried is:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()
```

But it doesn't work as expected.
Could anyone please help me out here?
Thank you.

Comment: `df['count'] = df.sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `True`s are processing like `1` you can use `sum`:

```
df['count'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

If `TRUE`s are strings:

```
df['count'] = df.eq('TRUE').sum(axis=1)
```